# Normal Deep Breathing vs Buddhism Basic Meditation

Tags: meditation, meditation-breath

What is the difference between normal deep breathing that recommended by all western Doctors vs Buddhism Basic Meditation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Difference is one doesn't "force" his breathing in meditation to be long or short, deep or shallow. One's just "aware" of their in and out breaths. If it's a long one, s/he's aware that it's a long one; if it's short, s/he's aware that it's short. (ref: [MN 118](https://suttacentral.net/mn118/en/bodhi?reference=none&highlight=false) )

Comment: I guess the different is Buddhism fully focus in mind but medical deep breathing more focus using the organ using the belly ? Correct me from wrong

Comment: @ruben2020 can comment also. Sadhu.

Comment: Breathing should just be breathing.  That's what makes it hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Santa's answer is 100% correct, but I'd add something.  Buddhist breathing doesn't necessarily come out of your nose or mouth.  Watch your breath.  You may discover something interesting.